# How to dynamically change the src of <img />

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to continually change the `src` of an `<img />` tag in loop.

I've tried this, but it's wouldn't work:

```
<img src="" />
<script>
    (function(){
        for(var i = 1; true; i++)
        {
            var str = "C:\abc\" + i + ".png";
            $("img").prop("src", str);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The loop is likely to be faster than the loading of the images. Do you want to wait until each images is displayed before telling the browser to load the next?

Comment: @JasonAller, brilliant idea, would you please provide me how to do that?

Comment: Are you planning on only using this locally from disk, or will it ever be used over the network? What other requirements are there?

Comment: @JasonAller, the images are hosted in the server and sent to the enduser's browser.

Comment: And you want to send them one after another with no delay?

Comment: in fact I'm trying to display them continually as a video.

Comment: I suggest then that you look at H.264 encoding a stream of the images.

Comment: Is there any sample for that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the **.attr()** method: https://api.jquery.com/attr/

Answer (score 1):

Try something like:

```
$('img').attr('src', str);
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the image loading is actually done asynchronously, and you've got an infinite loop that continuously resets the img, initiating a new load, i.e. before one load finishes another has started.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but rather than a while loop, maybe you should try using [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval):

```
    setInterval(function() {
        var str = "foo" + i + ".png";
        i = i + 1;
        $("img").prop("src", str);
    }, 1000);
```

which would change the picture every second until you run `clearInterval`.

If you really want to load the images as fast as possible, you could use the load event, i.e. load the next image as soon as the last one is done, with something like:

```
    $("img").prop("src", str).load(function () {
        i = i+1;
        var str = "foo" + i + ".png";
        $("img").prop("src", str);
    });
```

Though, the result would look pretty messy.

P.S. - I see from the comments that what you're really trying to do is show a video.  What really makes sense to convert your still images to a video and use a `<video>` tag, but if you were really determined to do it this way, you'd want a more consistent framerate so you'd probably want to use `setInterval` with an appropriate interval, or `requestAnimationFrame`.

Comment: This won't work as `i` is not changing during intervals.